# Four square Lagrange Theorem.

Tags: arithmetic, sums-of-squares

Today teacher tell us that every natural number is the sum of four positive squares.

and let us this work:

write $747004$ as the sum of $4$ squares.

I'm at high school and don't understand the proof in Wikipedia.

Comment: this is not a easy problem for high school

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: pray hahaha, or you can run it on python

Comment: Not quite correctly stated, every natural number is the sum of four squares, but we need to include $0$ as a square. The only way to write three this way is $$  3 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 $$

Comment: teacher says 0 is a natural number, teacher also says in other countries 0 is not a natural number. why?

Comment: Does not matter, if that is how you are using the phrase then you are alright.

Comment: Wikipedia is problematic, to put it charitably. As for $0$ being a natural number or not, that's a distraction. I would instead say every positive number can be expressed as the sum of four or fewer nonzero squares. The numbers that *require* the full four nonzero squares are of the form $8k + 7$.

Comment: Presumably he was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem which gives two proofs, neither of which I'm willing to vouch for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm lucky, if you rest $1$ to $747004$ you have a number wich is divisible by $3$ and $1$ is a square

$$747004=1^2+499^2+499^2+499^2$$

Since Geoff Robinson comment, we have: 
$$ 747004=444^2+606^2+414^2+106^2 $$

Comment: i'm not sure if this is the only way to do it.

Comment: It certainly isn't the only way. For example, $747004 = 4 \times 186751$, and it's therefore to write $186751$ as a sum of $4$ integer squares, and then multiply each of those integers by $2$ to get $747004$ as a sum of squares of $4$ even integers.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson nice observation mate!

Answer (score 2):

there are  12537 integer quadruples $w \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq 0$ with
$w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 747004.$  Since $747004 = 4 \cdot 186751,$ and
$186751 \equiv 7 \pmod 8.$ As a result, $747004$ is not the sum of three squares, so there are no quadruples with any zeroes. Here are some form the beginning, middle, and end:

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     863      47       5       1
     863      43      19       5
     863      41      23       5
     863      37      29       5
     863      35      31       7
     863      35      29      13
     862      62      10       4
     862      60      18       6
     862      58      20      14
     862      54      30      12
     862      52      34      10
     862      50      38       4
     862      50      28      26
     862      46      38      20
     862      42      36      30
     861      75       7       3
     861      69      29       9
     861      65      27      27
     861      63      33      25
     861      61      39      21
     861      57      47      15
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     499     499     499       1
     499     499     491      89
     499     499     461     191
     499     499     419     271
     499     497     437     245
     499     481     421     299
     499     475     467     233
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     462     438     430     396
     461     443     425     397
     461     437     433     395
     460     446     422     398
     458     452     410     406
     457     455     433     379
     457     453     411     405
     457     441     435     393
     455     449     443     377
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```